# Showing leader board stats from JSON with Discord.py via Embed

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to create a leaderboard to show the different stats the users collect when messaging the discord chatroom. I'm storing the data via JSON file and was wondering if I am on the right track or if there was a better way to display the stats with an Embed?

Edit: Edited the code to display what changes were made. New question is, how could I display 11-20 with a page forward? Tried the code below but when it goes to display 11-20, it sends #11 as an embed, then #11-12 as an embed, etc, etc and doesn't stop at 20, just keeps sending more embeds.

```
client = discord.Client()

try:
    with open("cash.json") as fp:
        cash = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    cash = {}

def save_cash():
    with open("cash.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(cash, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_dollars(user: discord.User, dollars: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in cash:
        cash[id] = {}
    cash[id]["dollars"] = cash[id].get("dollars", 0) + dollars
    print("{} now has {} dollars".format(user.name, cash[id]["dollars"]))
    save_cash()

def get_dollars(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in cash:
        return cash[id].get("dollars", 0)
    return 0

client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!lb cash'):
        cash_leaderboard = sorted(cash, key=lambda x : cash[x].get('dollars', 0), reverse=True)
        msg = ''
        for number, user in enumerate(cash_leaderboard):
            msg += '{0}. <@!{1}> {2} Dollars\n\n'.format(number +1, user, cash[user].get('dollars', 0))
            if number == 10:
                break
            else:
                number += 1

            embed = discord.Embed(
            title="TOP BALLER LEADERBOARD\nBallers:",
            color=0x24d7cf,
            description=msg
        )
            embed.set_author(name="BOT", icon_url="")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="")
            embed.set_footer(text="BOT", icon_url="")

        lb_msg = await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
        await client.add_reaction(lb_msg, "⏩")
        lb_wait = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji="⏩", user=message.author, message=lb_msg, timeout=1800)
        if lb_wait:
            await client.delete_message(lb_msg)
            cash_leaderboard2 = sorted(cash, key=lambda x : cash[x].get('dollars', 0), reverse=True)
            msg = ''
            for number, user in enumerate(cash_leaderboard2):
                msg += '{0}. <@!{1}> {2} Dollars\n\n'.format(number +11, user, cash[user].get('dollars', 0))
                if number == 20:
                    break
                else:
                    number += 1

                embed = discord.Embed(
                title="TOP BALLER LEADERBOARD 11-20\nBallers:",
                color=0x24d7cf,
                description=msg
            )
                embed.set_author(name="BOT", icon_url="")
                embed.set_thumbnail(url="")
                embed.set_footer(text="BOT", icon_url="")

            await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
```

Comment: Your `on_message` looks like it's missing parts.  What is `dollars_count`, for example?

Comment: Oops! I meant to delete that, I replaced it with "get_dollars" to pull the dollars from the json file, but I'm not sure if this will pull a leaderboard the way I want it.

Comment: There are two modes to most leaderboards: showing the top X scorers, and showing the location of a specific person along with their rank and a few people above and below them.  You should write a method that returns a limited number of pairs `(name, amount)` sorted by descending amount.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick! After doing a little research, I came up with this, but it seems to post all of the data from JSON from the most to least. Is there a way to set a max to 10? I've edited my original post to edit the code in that I am using.

Comment: My brain was fried looking at all this code. I added the below code before sending msg and it works.

`if number == 10:
                break
            else:
                number += 1
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)`

Comment: Hi. Can you post the full code? I'm doing a somewhat similar thing with my bot. Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: @Person edited the code to reflect the entire thing.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I've tried to edit the code to reflect a "page forward" option to display 11-20 but the current code sends multiple embeds just adding one more person to each embed and doesn't stop at 20, do you have a suggestion?